# Texture and image handling with (py)OpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, python-imaging-library, pyopengl

I very recently started getting into pygame and eventually into pyOpenGL (only using two dimensions), since drawing images to the screen with pygame stutters. However, I came across two issues, that I, for the life of me, can't figure out how to fix. Namely handling two+ textures and getting around the coordinate incompatibility of pygame and OpenGL when loading the images.

I made a simple class called `Thingie1`:

```
class Thingie1:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = 0
        self.height = 0
        self.sprite = "imageOne.png"
        self.lastsprite = ""
        self.img_data = 0
        self.load()

    def load(self):
        if self.sprite != self.lastsprite:
            im = open(self.sprite)
            self.width, self.height, self.img_data = im.size[0], im.size[1], im.tobytes("raw", "RGB", 0, -1)
            self.lastsprite = self.sprite

            self.Texture = glGenTextures(1)
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.Texture)
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT)
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT)
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, self.width, self.height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, self.img_data)
            glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        else:
            return

    def draw(self):
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glLoadIdentity()
        glTranslate(self.x, self.y, 0)
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        glVertex(0, 0, 0)
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0)
        glVertex(self.width, 0, 0)
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1)
        glVertex(self.width, self.height, 0)
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1)
        glVertex(0, self.height, 0)
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0)
        glEnd()
        glFlush()
```

and an exact copy (for now) of the mentioned class, called `Thingie2`. (The `open()` function is from PILLOW's Image package (`from PIL.Image import open`).)

I then call

```
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((1024,768), pygame.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.OPENGL)

if True:
    glClearColor(*(0,0,0,255))
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluOrtho2D(0, 1024, 768, 0)
    Thing1 = Thingie1(200,200)
    Thing2 = Thingie2(0,0)

    while True:
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        Thing2.load()
        Thing1.load()

        Thing2.draw()
        Thing1.draw()
        pygame.display.flip()
```

to draw `Thing1` atop of `Thing2`, which works partially; before, when the `load()` and `draw()` functions were merged into one, it textured the objects correctly, but wasn't exactly kind to my computer. Now, it textures both class instances with Thing2's texture, which is the first issue.

The second issue is, that the drawn image is rotated by 180°. I've tried using matplotlib, cv2 and other packages to load the image, but the closest I came to fixing this was when I modified the `glTexImage2D` line with `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, self.width, self.height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, self.img_data[::-1])` (using PIL.Image's `open()`), but that draws the image in grey+blue scale (?).

So, **firstly**, how does pyOpenGL handle textures in general? I'd expect that both the textures would be stored in their own respective `self.Texture`s. Is the problem that they're both bound to `GL_TEXTURE_2D`? How would I go about distinguishing the two textures from each other?

**Secondly**, is there a better way to load an image or is there a way to format the image pixel byte array in a way, so that it can be reversed easily (that would work for RGBA images as well)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, that drawing by [`glBegin`/`glEnd`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml) sequences and the fixed function matrix stack  is deprecated since decades. See [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) and [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL).
Read about [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification) and [Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader) for a state of the art way of rendering.

---

> Now, it textures both class instances with Thing2's texture, which is the first issue.

Two-dimensional texturing is enabled by [`glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnable.xml) and can be disabled by `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`.
If texturing is enables then the texture wich is currently bound when the geometry is drawn by the [`glBegin`/`glEnd`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml) sequence is applied.

You have to bind the proper texture before you draw the geometry:

```py
def draw(self):

    # [...]

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.Texture)
    glBegin()

    # [...]     

    glEnd()
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
```

---

> The second issue is, that the drawn image is rotated by 180°

When [`glVertex`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertex.xml) is called, the the current texture coordinates are associated with the vertex coordinate. The texture coordinate is set by [`glTexCoord2f`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexCoord.xml).

This means [`glTexCoord2f`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexCoord.xml) has to be done **before** [`glVertex`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertex.xml).

```py
glBegin(GL_QUADS)

glTexCoord2f(0, 0)
glVertex(0, 0, 0)

glTexCoord2f(0, 1)
glVertex(self.width, 0, 0)

glTexCoord2f(1, 1)
glVertex(self.width, self.height, 0)

glTexCoord2f(1, 0)
glVertex(0, self.height, 0)

glEnd()
```